# ionic & cordova cropping image then upload it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, image-processing, ionic-framework

After taking a picture through cordova camera plugin and display in the html, I want a user to have a choice whether to edit it (cropping, set aspect ratio, resize it), or to upload it as it is .

Is there any way to do so?

HTML

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Photos</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content ng-controller="ImgCtrl" padding="true">
    <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="takePhoto()"> Take Photo </button>    
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="text-align: center">
</ion-content>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {                  
  var options = {                    
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        correctOrientation: true,
        targetWidth: 800,
        targetHeight: 1100,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false                  
    };                      
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        // Saving the image  for later access
                            
        $scope.imageURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Photo taken',
            duration: 1000
        });
                       
    }, function(err) {     
         $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Error  ...',
            duration: 900
        });                               
    });                
}
```

Comment: but you do have, allowEdit does that for you. After you take a picture you get an edit screen, you crop, and confirm -> you receive a cropped image

Comment: I need to crop through a JavaScript function , Allow edit bring the native cropping app on the phone

Comment: I want to give the user a choice after taking a picture , not to inforce edting option  on him .

Comment: there are a lot of plugins for cropping photos, like this 1 https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop

Comment: how can I implement it with my code , can you provide me with an example .
Thanks ;)

Comment: By the way, unless your code is in platform.ready, get rid of the $rootscope and use $scope.imageUri instead. You'll have your picture there and use any of the cropping plugins on it

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-camera-crop/14661/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133478/discussion-between-egycode-and-marko).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL, the response will be a url and you can pass it directly pass url to ng-src. To your code, your "imageURI" actually is a string with base64 string of an image.

Comment: I have found this library , any idea how can I use it with my code https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

Comment: install cropperjs through bower. Read official documentation and follow it. It should be very simple to use.